# Cannot serialize geodjango model data to json for passing back to website

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, geodjango

I have some models that are pretty straight forward in their relationship:

```
class CesiumEntity(models.Model):
    be_number = models.CharField(max_length=100) #the number assigned to a foot print to distinguish
    zone_id = models.ForeignKey('ZoneEntity', null=True, blank=True)
    sensor = models.CharFIeld(max_length=100) # sensor this entity is from
    ....
```

and

```
class ZoneEntity(models.Model):
    zone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    #zone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mpoly = models.PolygonField() #this should grow and shrink for the most representative one...
    objects = models.GeoManager() 
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

I am trying to get data from them as a join:

```
object_list = ZoneEntity.objects.filter(cesiumentity__sensor__in=sensor).distinct('zone_number')
```

Which should be equivalent to the SQL:

```
SELECT distinct(zone_number) FROM SWSITE_ZONEENTITY INNER JOIN SWSITE_CESIUMENTITY ON SWSITE_ZONEENTITY.zone_number = SWSITE_CESIUMENTITY.zone_id_id  WHERE SWSITE_CESIUMENTITY.sensor = 'RADARSAT-2'
```

So this gives me all these zone numbers based on a sensor that is selected on the UI. This is great, for each `zonenumber` there are many of the other things (`CesiumEntities`). So I want to roll all that up as a json object to send back to my web interface.

Something like this

```
zoneEntity.ZoneNumber        # fromDB
zoneEntity.mpoly (Geometry)  # fromDB
zoneEntity.cesiumEntities    # list of all the cesiumentities with the
                             # zonenumber and with the sensor selected.
```

Ideally if I could get something to work for the serialization that has the data automatically:

```
  jdata =serialize('geojson', object_list, 
             geometry_field = 'mpoly');
```

But this fails in numerous ways... mostly the properties and lists are not there or in the right format.

So I am trying to build my own object to send back: (Though I am sure this is the hard way):

```
returnData = []
secondData =[]
object_list = ZoneEntity.objects.filter(cesiumentity__sensor__in=sensor).distinct('zone_number')
print len(object_list)
for ze in object_list:
    second_list = CesiumEntity.objects.filter(zone_id = ze.zone_number)
    returnData.append(ze.zone_number)
    returnData.append(ze.mpoly)
    for sl in second_list:
         secondData.append(sl.sensor)
         secondData.append(sl.resource_location)
         secondData.append(sl.name)
         secondData.append(sl.country_code)
         secondData.append(sl.corner_coords)
         secondData.append(sl.target_name)
         secondData.append(sl.collection_date)
     returnData.append(secondData)
```

(Not totally sure the above is the right way to get things in the format to get ready for json serialization)
So I want to serialize returnData to json so I can get all the zones display them on a map and then when one is clicked show all the cesium entities that were in the area.  So far when I try to call json.dumps I get an error :

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': returnData})) #was jdata
```

Results in :

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Polygon object at 0x10cb1a880> is not JSON serializable
```

I did see this:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

I cannot tell if this is what I must do or if the problem is much simpler and I am just misunderstanding something

I thought it might be an issue with mpoly so I looked up some items (found something on `mapping` with shapely) tried that and got no where (even had a SO question on that too:  [shapely mapping gives error on my geometry when serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450272/shapely-mapping-gives-error-on-my-geometry-when-serializing))

Comment: Have you tried removing `mpoly` from the `returnData` to prove that it is the only problem?

Comment: Actually good call, mpoly is a problem (it cannot serialize the Polygon as it is not in whatever format json.dumps needs the mpoly to be, and I cannot figure out how to do a equivalent geojson.dumps )  but there is another problem with my  secondData.append(sl.collection_date), it won't be able to serialize that either (figured out after commenting out the mpoly).  So it is like with both mpoly and collection_date they need to be more stringified than python objects.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a `JSONEncoder` class that checks the object type and if it's `Polygon` or `datetime` you can return a custom representation of the object. You'll obviously need to create a corresponding deserializer if you need to go the other way too. You'd call it like this `json.dumps(returnData, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)` https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder

Comment: I wish I could force a geojson, and I am not sure why the serializer in django generally works so well either.   If I could just stringify the two pieces I was hoping json.dumps would take care of the rest.  I will look at this docs though I have never seen this cls custom jsonencoder thing.

Comment: Wow turns out mpoly.json seems to give me a json string.  Now I just have to figure out how to consume in javascript the returnData (from above in code) that is sent across the wire!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own serializer for the model in a file called `serializers.py`, by utilizing [rest_framework's serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/):

```
class ZoneEntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ZoneEntity
        fields = ("the", "fields", "that", "you want", "serialized",)
```

After that, on the view that you are making the join, keep

```
object_list = ZoneEntity.objects.filter(cesiumentity__sensor__in=sensor).distinct('zone_number')
```

assuming that is correct for your case.

Finally create the response:

`res = ZoneEntitySerializer(object_list, many=True)` *(the many=True let's your serializer know that it will serialize multiple objects)*

and `return HttpResponse(res.data)`

Now the response must be in JSON format.